# Find Missing Row in Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a SQL table as below. I want find missing B2 for all ColA having B1.

| Id | ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 |
| 2 | A1 | B2 |
| 3 | A2 | B1 |
| 4 | A3 | B1 |

Expect Result: A2,A3

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why have you tagged both Oracle and SQL Server? Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are expecting.

```
 select ColA from table where ColB = 'B1' 
    and ColA not in (select ColA from table where ColB = 'B2')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports `WITH`, then you can do:

```sql
  WITH 
     with_b1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT ColA FROM t WHERE ColB = 'B1'),
     with_b2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT ColA FROM t WHERE ColB = 'B2')
SELECT ColA 
  FROM with_b1
 WHERE ColA NOT IN (SELECT ColA FROM with_b2)
```

Otherwise try

```sql
SELECT ColA 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ColA FROM t WHERE ColB = 'B1')
 WHERE ColA NOT IN (SELECT ColA FROM t WHERE ColB = 'B2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as follows:

```
select colA
 from your_Table t
group by colA
Having count(distinct colB) <> (select count(distinct tt.colB) from your_Table tt)
```